Making Menubar and TabbedPage work together in Maui
When I add a MenuBar to a TabbedPage the MenuBar sits on the right of the tabs, but I want the MenuBar above the tabs preferably in the Titlebar, but I don't think that is possible so just above the tabs would be awesome.
Here is my XAML and a picture of what happens on the page currently:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stamp"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Stamp.Components.Pages"
             x:Class="Stamp.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

    <TabbedPage.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="File"></MenuBarItem>
        <MenuBarItem Text="Edit"></MenuBarItem>
    </TabbedPage.MenuBarItems>

    <ContentPage Title="Home">


        <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:CanvasPage}" />
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>

    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="File-001">
        <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView2" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:CanvasPage}" />
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>
    </ContentPage>


</TabbedPage>

Image of the MenuBar rendering on the left of the tabs


This is a feature request on GitHub : Can menu bar set in Caption\Title Bar? #7160. You may follow it up. You may also try customizing the Titlebar like this Customize the Windows 10 title bar using .NET MAUI
